# How can i run java command with Nodejs

Tags: java, node.js, command

I want to run a java command with Nodejs

This command works with me on bat file

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe" -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -classpath "<path>\app\netlogo-6.1.1.jar" org.nlogo.headless.Main  --model modelname.nlogo --setup-file setup.xml --experiment experiment1 --table table-output.csv
```

How can i run this command with Nodejs ? 
Have I to use Node child_process, and it's possible to run this after deploying my app on server ?

Comment: You can use [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to run and spawn commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it executed in the main application asynchronously:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('YOUR COMMAND HERE', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

or with a child process that will report back to your primary application via event emitter:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const YOUR_COMMAND = spawn('YOUR_COMMAND', ['--arg1', 'value1', '--arg2', 'value2']);

YOUR_COMMAND.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

YOUR_COMMAND.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

YOUR_COMMAND.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

But this is where you should go: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html,
my answers are just retreads of the provided examples